# making 45 degree vectors in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, graph

I am trying to make 45 degree vector arrows in a chart using the snippet of matplotlib python code:

```
soa_tau = []

def my_range(start, end, step):
while start <= end:
    yield start
    start += step

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=6, figsize=(11, 8.5))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.8, left=0.07, right=0.97, wspace=0.4)

a=0

for tau in range(0,121,24):
    if (tau==0):    
    depth_count= []
soa = []
for h in my_range(0,600,100):
    if (tau==0):
        depth_count.append(-h)
    xvect=0.125
    yvect=0.125
    result = [0.2,-h,xvect,yvect]

    soa.append(result)
    a=a+1;
soa_tau.append(soa)

axes[0].set_ylabel('depth (m)')
aa=0
for ax in axes:
    soa=soa_tau[aa]
    X,Y,U,V = zip(*soa)
    ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V,angles='xy',width=0.003,headwidth=0.4,color='r',scale=1,zorder=2)
    ax.tick_params(axis='both',which='major', labelsize=6)
    ax.set_xlabel('Speed (m/s)')

    aa=aa+1

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Now I am trying to produce the following figure: [image]

However as you can see in the figure the vectors are flat lines.  I am trying to make the lines be at 45 degree angles which is what I would expect from the x and y components of the vectors being equal.  My guess is having the multiple figures complicated things.  However I still need to have these figures available.  Is there any way that this code can be tweaked so that the vectors display at 45 degrees instead of 0 degrees as shown in the figure?  I also want to be able to maintain the length of the vectors as shown in the figure.

Comment: for them to appear at 45deg angle your x and y scale need to be the same

Comment: Not quite sure how to scale things.  I am trying to figure out the ratio of the height of each chart to the width.  Is this the correct approach?

Comment: forgot scale XY in the quiver.

Comment: there might be a better way but you can do ax.set_xlim and ax.set_ylim to directly set them and get the ratio that way